# Python PEP 8 docstring line length

Tags: python, coding-style, pep8

I've recently begun figuring it would be a good idea to follow PEP 8. I made my editor display the 80-column mark and am now attempting to wrap lines to fit in it. My question is this. In PEP 8 it says:

> Limit all lines to a maximum of 79 characters.

Makes sense.

> [...] For flowing long blocks of text (docstrings or comments), limiting the length to 72 characters is recommended.

Why 72? Why isn't 79 fine for docstrings or comments?

Comment: I am a bit confused. Is the 72-character limit for comments including indentation or not?

Comment: Also, narrow columns of longform text are more readable, think newspapers.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I believe it's a hangover from text documents:

> At the end of the typewriter age, most designs were geared toward 72
>   CPL, derived from a pitch of 12 characters per inch, multiplied by 6
>   inches (see for example IBM Selectric). This would ensure at least 1
>   inch for each margin, with the U.S. government at the time having
>   standardized on 8 1/2×11" paper.

[Source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characters_per_line)

> Many plain text documents still conform to 72 CPL out of tradition.

I think this is just as docstrings are often used in contexts outside of code, so it makes sense to conform to the style most plain text documents use to try and remain as consistent as possible. For example, the text of `man` pages are generally wrapped to 72 characters. By limiting docstrings to 72 characters, the output of `help()` mirrors this.

[This question on Programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/148677/why-is-80-characters-the-standard-limit-for-code-width) may also be relevant.

Comment: As a comment - this is all a guess - I have no source stating that this is the reason, it just seems likely to me - if anyone has anything more concrete, I'd be interested.

Comment: It is a good guess though.

Comment: The text was added by Guido in [this changeset](http://hg.python.org/peps/comparison/5f37d8cda9c1/pep-0008.txt) so you'd have to ask him for his source. It could be detailed on the mailinglists.

Comment: Having scoured the list archives from around that time I cannot find any discussion on the change. Whatever source Guido based this on is not revealed there.

Answer (score 4):

Docstrings are typically indented with their function, and start and end with triple quotes:

```
def foo(bar, baz):
    """Frobnicate the foobars into baz

    Parameters are ham and spammed.

    """
```

That's 79 - 4 - 3 = 72 characters left.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the 72 character limit is intended to include these.

Comment: Hrm, perhaps. Not sure myself, but you may have a point with your answer too.

Comment: This only holds for the first line of the docstring, right? After this one, you only are restricted to 79 - 4 = 75 characters. How can one make it easy to respect the 72 limitation after the first line?

Comment: @Iago-lito: My interpretation for this answer is that only the first line would by limited to 72 characters, subsequent lines would get 75. If you disagree you'll have to manually check for this restriction or use a linter that supports checking this restriction.

Comment: But I LOVE this interpretation =D Is it PEP-compliant?

Comment: @Iago-lito: it is if you interpret the PEP this way. That's the issue here, the PEP is open to multiple interpretations.

Comment: I had never considered PEP like a religion-book so far.. but hey, does it not look like? ;)

Comment: This makes no sense. If your limit is 72, your indent or quote has zero impact on that, unless somehow you are saying line length minus indent and triple quote must be less than 72. For example, a class methods has 2 indents (at least), but the docstring line length limit is still 72, however, the available characters changes with the second indent.

Comment: Yes, indentation and triple quotes are included in the char limit, from the man Guido van Rossum himself:
https://github.com/python/peps/issues/884#issuecomment-456993432

Answer (score 0):

The reason that lines should be 79 characters is so that they can fit into an 80 character wide terminal (apparently they still exist). The reason that 72 characters are used on the docstring is that this means that you have equal padding on both sides (docstrings are indented, after all) and still fit into the 80 character width.

Comment: But don't 80 characters fit into an 80 character wide terminal too?!

Comment: Do you have a source for this?

Comment: Wrong, padding counts towards the 72 char limit, see Guido van Rossum’s comment:
https://github.com/python/peps/issues/884#issuecomment-456993432

Comment: @Spartan Could be. I had a source when I wrote this in 2013, but it seemed like it had little value to go back and add it.